# AWS quicksight parseInt() returns null

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I'm trying to generate a QuickSight analysis with a simple .csv file. The file contains some arbitrary data like

```
Yifei, 24, Male, 2
Joe, 30, Male, 3
Winston, 40, Male, 7
Emily, 18, Female, 5
Wendy, 32, Female, 4
```

I placed the file in an S3 bucket, and then use AWS Athena to parse that into a table. The table treats all columns as strings, and I can query it properly

`SELECT * FROM users`

returns

```
    name    age gender  consumed
1   Yifei   24  Male    2
2   Joe     30  Male    3
3   Winston 40  Male    7
4   Emily   18  Female  5
5   Wendy   32  Female  4
```

Okay so far so good. Then in QuickSight, I import the table as dataset, and it's properly displayed under fields with the correct values. The only problem remaining is that `age` and `consumed` are treated as strings, not numbers. So, I created two calculated fields:

```
age_calc: parseInt({age})
consumed_calc: parseInt({consume})
```

[image: Screenshot of fields]

Works just fine, now under the fields I can see the newly created fields with correct values. However, once I try to create actual visualization (For example, a pie chart with how much everyone consumed) using the field `consumed_calc`, the value of `consumed_calc` is just null.
[image: Screenshot of the pie chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. Basically, csv does not work very well with spaces, so despite the calculated fields showing correct result in preview, when parsed the field " 23" gets an error. Removing the spaces in the original .csv file solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

the best practice is not to use calculated field for this,
Go to the "Edit dataset" part in datasets,
simply click on the three dots at the right of the field name quicksight console, and choose "change data type" to integer

It will be easier to you not to add calculated fields simply for this 'simple' calculation